# How to print values/scale on the y-axis of a bar plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

This is what I have done so far. My problen, however, is that I can't print the values/scale on the y-axis of a bar plot? Any ideas? What other stylings whould I add?

```
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib import pyplot

%matplotlib inline

sb.axes_style("white")
sb.set_style("ticks")
sb.set_context("talk")

x1 = np.array(['U', 'G'])
x2 = np.array(['H', 'W'])

f, (ax1, ax2) = pyplot.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

y1 = np.array([831824, 3306662])
y2 = np.array([1798043, 1508619])

sb.barplot(x1, y1, ci=None, palette="Blues", hline=.0001, ax=ax1)
sb.barplot(x1, y2, ci=None, palette="Reds", hline=.0001, ax=ax2)

ax1.set_ylabel("Occurences")
ax1.set_xlabel("Totals")

ax2.set_ylabel("Occurences")
ax2.set_xlabel("Types")

sb.despine(bottom=True)
pyplot.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])
pyplot.tight_layout(h_pad=3)

sb.despine()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @john-cipponeri's answer:

Using functions operating on axes called using `pyplot.*` only operate on the last opened axis, in your case `ax2`, which is the the right plot. Use the axis instance to take it effect where you want. Replace tour last block of your code with this one and I hope it corresponds to your expected plot:

```
ax1.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-')
ax2.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-')
pyplot.tight_layout(h_pad=3)
sb.despine()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a line style.

```
pyplot.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-')
```

Comment: pyplot.setp(f.axes, yticks=[]) You're setting yticks to an empty array, shouldn't it contain the values for your y-axis?

Comment: Awesome, it works, but only on the right-side subplot. What is the reason for that?